# Serial Port communication using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, serial-port, com-port

I am trying to set up serial port communication with a ViewSonic Display using PowerShell.
I send a request for the display status either on or off and should get a 9 digit reply
Either 56 48 49 114 108 48 48 49 13 reply for on
Or 56 48 49 114 108 48 48 48 13 reply for off
When I run the code, I only get a one-digit reply
When I add a second read, I get the remaining 8
But when I add a break point and step through it using the debugger, I get all 9 on the first read.
Any ideas what could be causing this odd behavior?
Any suggestions on any better ways to do this?
See code and results below.

```
PS C:\Users\james\Desktop>  [Byte[]] $request = 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x67, 0x6C, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x0D
$portreturn = [System.Byte[]]::CreateInstance([System.Byte], 9)
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3, 9600, None, 8, one
$port.Open()
$port.Write($request, 0, $request.Count)
$port.Read($portreturn, 0, $portreturn.Length)
Write-Host "portreturn1" $portreturn -foreground black -BackgroundColor white
$port.Read($portreturn, 0, $portreturn.Length)
Write-Host "portreturn2" $portreturn -foreground black -BackgroundColor white
$port.Close()
```

1
portreturn1 56 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

8
portreturn2 48 49 114 108 48 48 49 13 0

PS C:\Users\james\Desktop> C:\Users\james\Desktop\VStest2a.ps1

Hit Line breakpoint on 'C:\Users\james\Desktop\VStest2a.ps1:4'
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\james\Desktop>>

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\james\Desktop>>

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\james\Desktop>>
9

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\james\Desktop>>
portreturn1 56 48 49 114 108 48 48 49 13

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\james\Desktop>>

Picture for clarity:
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

It's not odd behavior, it can happen normally if you use the [Read() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) on the serial port.

The serial port communicates in 1-byte units at a minimum. There is no concept of packets like TCP/IP.
You need to get and save the data and size of the Read() result and add a process to check if all the data was received normally.
Perhaps by adjusting the value of the [ReadTimeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), it may be possible to finish Read() after receiving all the data.
However, since the initial value should be [InfiniteTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.infinitetimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), changing the value cannot be expected to have any effect.

Alternatively, if all the data you receive is a string, ending in 13(carriage return=`\r`) and it doesn't appear in the middle of the data, you can use the [ReadTo() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readto?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).
Or, you could get similar results by calling the [ReadLine() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) with the [NewLine property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) set to 13(carriage return=`\r`) in a similar way.

Please try various things.

For example, if the end of the data is 10(line feed=`\n`), you can call it like this article.
[Writing and Reading info from Serial Ports](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/writing-and-reading-info-from-serial-ports/)

Comment: **Thanks, kunif!**
I will definitely try these suggestions and I appreciate the thoroughness of your reply.
The reason that it seemed odd to me is that it worked as expected in debug mode but not when running the code normally.

Comment: And to add clarity yes all of the data sent and received should end in 13(carriage return=\r)  
I send the request  
0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x67, 0x6C, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x0D  
56 48 49 103 108 48 48 48 13  

And am looking for one of these as the reply  
56 48 49 114 108 48 48 48 13 the reply for off  
56 48 49 114 108 48 48 49 13 the reply for on